# C# Change usercontrol labeltext and background color

Tags: c#

My problem is simple. I want to click a panel in `Form1` that will cause label1 in a `userControl1`, which will be placed upon form2 to change to "Text".

Clicking this panel would also change the background color of said `userControl1`. I receive the error `"'TileInterFaceTest.Usercontrol1.label1' due to its protection level"` which frankly baffles me.

Even running the color change code separately it simply doesn't achieve the desired result.

To be clear, I'm quite a novice when it comes to C# and programming. I've been working with Visual Basic until now so the concept of classes, methods and objects are slightly confusing to me.

Here is my code for `Form1`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            UserControl1 userControl1 = new UserControl1();
            form2.Show();
            userControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            userControl1.LabelText = "Text";

        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Code for UserControl1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public String LabelText
        {
            get
            {
                return label1.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                label1.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public UserControl1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also should REALLY rename your variables from the defaults generated.

Comment: I simply wanted something that would work. After figuring out how to actually make the program carry out the desired result I shall rename the variable appropriately. But right now it seems a little unnecessary.

Comment: I would disagree.  If you're just using generated code, sure.  Once you start writing "Code Behind" such as the event handlers it's time to use proper names.

Comment: Renaming variables appropriately after you get your program working is like sharpening your knife after you've finished cutting with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`label1` is a [private](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx) field, which means you cannot access it outside of the class `UserControl1`.

What you could do is add a public property in the definition of the class `UserControl1`:

```
public String LabelText {
    get {
        return label1.Text;
    }
    set {
        label1.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Then use this property to modify the value of the Text of `label1`:

```
private void panel1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form2.Show();
    userControl1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    userControl1.LabelText = "Text";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But this is the second time I have used the exact same solution and I don't seem to get any sort of result. Is there anything I could possibly be doing wrong with the classes or object definitions?

Comment: Edit your question and post the code you're using. We cannot help you without seeing the code.

Comment: Added code for both Form1 and UserControl1. I'm sure I've missed something blindingly obvious. I appreciate your patience.